# How to fix VersionConflict locking failure in pipenv?

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, pipenv, pipenv-install

I'm using `pipenv` inside a docker container. I tried installing a package and found that the installation succeeds (gets added to the Pipfile), but the locking keeps failing. Everything was fine until yesterday. Here's the error:

```
(app) root@7284b7892266:/usr/src/app# pipenv install scrapy-djangoitem
Installing scrapy-djangoitem…
Adding scrapy-djangoitem to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (6d808e) out of date, updating to (27ac89)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 807, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 803, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages, parse_only=parsed.parse_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 785, in _main
    resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 758, in resolve_packages
    results = clean_results(results, resolver, project)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 634, in clean_results
    reverse_deps = project.environment.reverse_dependencies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 376, in environment
    self._environment = self.get_environment(allow_global=allow_global)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 366, in get_environment
    environment.extend_dists(pipenv_dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 127, in extend_dists
    extras = self.resolve_dist(dist, self.base_working_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 122, in resolve_dist
    deps |= cls.resolve_dist(dist, working_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 121, in resolve_dist
    dist = working_set.find(req)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-lp47FrbD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 642, in find
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (importlib-metadata 2.0.0 (/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-lp47FrbD/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"'))
(app) root@7284b7892266:/usr/src/app#
```

What could be wrong?

EDIT
After removing `Pipfile.lock` and trying to install a package, I got:

```
(app) root@ef80787b5c42:/usr/src/app# pipenv install httpx
Installing httpx…
Adding httpx to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
⠏ Locking...Resolving dependencies...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 252, in install
    site_packages=state.site_packages
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2202, in do_install
    skip_lock=skip_lock,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1303, in do_init
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1113, in do_lock
    keep_outdated=keep_outdated
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1323, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, sp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1136, in resolve
    result = c.expect(u"\n", timeout=environments.PIPENV_INSTALL_TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 215, in expect
    self.subprocess.expect(pattern=pattern, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 344, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/expect.py", line 181, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/expect.py", line 144, in timeout
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x7f81e99bec90>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile('\n')
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x7f81e99bec90>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile('\n')
(app) root@ef80787b5c42:/usr/src/app#
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are my debugging notes. Still not sure which package is causing the problem, but this does seem to fix it.

The error you get when you first run `pipenv install` with pipenv version `2020.8.13`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 252, in install
    site_packages=state.site_packages
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1928, in do_install
    site_packages=site_packages,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 580, in ensure_project
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 512, in ensure_virtualenv
    python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 999, in do_create_virtualenv
    project._environment.add_dist("pipenv")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 135, in add_dist
    self.extend_dists(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 127, in extend_dists
    extras = self.resolve_dist(dist, self.base_working_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 122, in resolve_dist
    deps |= cls.resolve_dist(dist, working_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 121, in resolve_dist
    dist = working_set.find(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 642, in find
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (importlib-metadata 2.0.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"'))
```

If you run `pip install -U pipenv` it seems to change the `importlib-metadata` version:

```
Installing collected packages: importlib-metadata
  Attempting uninstall: importlib-metadata
    Found existing installation: importlib-metadata 2.0.0
    Uninstalling importlib-metadata-2.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled importlib-metadata-2.0.0
Successfully installed importlib-metadata-1.7.0
```

Now if you run `pipenv install -d --skip-lock` it will finish. It seems like a library is requiring a version `>= importlib-metadata 2.0`.

When I pinned the following dependencies it didn't work at first when running `pipenv lock`, however, if I removed the lock file (`rm Pipenv.lock`) then it worked when I ran `pipenv lock` again.

```
virtualenv = "==20.0.31"
importlib-metadata = "==1.7.0"
```

Comment: Thanks, including `importlib-metadata` in the package list helped!

Comment: Thanks you. I had the same problem, and your solution helped me too!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing `importlib-metadata` version solved my problem.

Comment: You can try to debug using `pip install -U -r requirements.txt` and it should tell you where a package conflict lies.

Answer (score 13):

Try to remove `Pipefile.lock` before installing a package

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got another error. Please take a look at the question again. I have edited and added the error I got

Comment: It's the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating a virtual environment using python 3.7.12. The problem is gone using python 3.8.10. On Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

-- Delete the Pipfile in your project
-- run $pipenv lock

This should work. Before deleting you might also try
$pipenv lock --pre

Answer (score 0):

Exit out of the Virtual environment

```
exit
```

Then Upgrade pipenv

```
pip install pipenv --upgrade
```

Then enter into the virtual environment

```
pipenv shell
```

then try

```
pipenv install
```

it should work now

Answer (score -1):

Here are some steps we followed, while we faced "locking failed"

1.make env
2.source /etc/pyenv
3.pipenv install
4.pipenv graph
5. Shoot the respective testcase execution (it may vary based on requirements)

Hope it works!!!:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the `Pipfile.lock` then rerun `pipenv lock`.