# Trying to install numpy via pipenv but I receive this message "Locking Failed!"

Tags: pipenv, pipenv-install

I have tried to install numpy via pipenv, I can see here Installation Succeeded after that I got this

```
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
           Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!
```

```
PS C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\Desktop\Project 1> pipenv install numpy          
Installing numpy...
Adding numpy to Pipfile's [packages]...
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
           Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 867, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 853, in main
    _main(
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 833, in _main
    resolve_packages(
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 781, in resolve_packages
    results, resolver = resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 760, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 1103, in resolve_deps
    results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(  
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 892, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 682, in resolve
    self.constraints  # For some reason it is important to evaluate constraints before resolver context
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 635, in constraints
    self._constraints = [
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 635, in <listcomp>
    self._constraints = [
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 145, in parse_requirements    for parsed_line in parser.parse(filename, constraint):
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 328, in parse
    yield from self._parse_and_recurse(filename, constraint)
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 333, in _parse_and_recurse    for line in self._parse_file(filename, constraint):
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 370, in _parse_file       
    args_str, opts = self._line_parser(line)
  File "c:\users\majid's workstation\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\_internal\req\req_file.py", line 397, in parse_line        
    opts, _ = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(options_str), defaults)
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 315, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "C:\Users\Majid's Workstation\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 191, in read_token
    raise ValueError("No closing quotation")
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

Comment: have you seen and tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124931/how-to-fix-locking-failed-in-pipenv ?

Comment: Yes but still see the same message